# What is a satellite assembly?

Tags: .net, localization, assemblies

What is a satellite assembly, and how can we use it?

Comment: Exact dupe as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365569/what-is-a-satellite-assembly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Satellite assemblies are small assemblies that contain only resources and are specific to a particular language (or, more accurately, culture). For instance, say I have an assembly called "MyAssembly.dll". If I had translations for US English and Chinese (PRC), the file structure would look like this:

```
MyAssembly.dll
en-US/
    MyAssembly.resources.dll
zh-CN/
    MyAssembly.resources.dll
```

Each of the `.resources.dll` files would contain the data from any culture-specific resource files that would be in the project (they would take the form of `FileName.culture.resx`, so if we're talking about the US English translation of `Form1`'s resources, it would be `Form1.us-EN.resx`).

As for using these files, this is done automatically by the resource manager. In the generated code for a resources file (that gives you the property-based syntax for reading a resource's value) it uses the current UI culture, but you can override this by calling the `ResourceManager.GetString(string name, CultureInfo culture)` overload.

Answer (score 4):

Satellite assemblies are used for localizing your UI.

You can find out how to use them [here](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/multi-languagesupport/article.php/c5601/).

Answer (score 0):

1. A satellite assembly is a compiled library (DLL) that contains “localizable” resources specific to a given culture such as strings, bitmaps, etc.
2. You are likely to use satellite assemblies when creating a multilingual UI application. They are used to deploy applications in multiple cultures, with 1 satellite assembly per culture (default behavior)

More here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/07/22/introduction-to-satellite-assemblies.aspx