# Use NuGet to add a project assembly reference to a file named *.Resources.dll

Tags: nuget

NuGet excludes anything that ends ".Resources.dll" when determining which dlls in a package should be added as assembly references. This is designed to exclude the localised [satellite assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365569/what-is-a-satellite-assembly), but it means it is tricky to add a reference if you have a DLL that is called MyCompany.Resources.dll.

Are there any good workarounds for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked around this for now by following an example at https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1644, with some modifications.

I added a check for Website projects because they don't support the 'Add' method.

I added this after the `metadata` element in my **`nuspec`** file. (Probably only necessary if not you're using the `includereferencedprojects` option available in NuGet 2.5)

```
<files>
  <file src="bin\Release\Foo.Resources.dll" target="lib\net40" />
  <file src="bin\Release\Foo.Resources.pdb" target="lib\net40" />
  <file src="tools\*" target="tools" />
</files>
```

And then added these two files to a new **`tools`** folders in my project directory. (Note the fix to the way DLL path is passed to the `References.Add` method, compared to the codeplex example)

**`Install.ps1`**

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$resourcesDll = Join-Path $installPath "lib\net40\Foo.Resources.dll"
Write-Host "Adding resources DLL from " $resourcesDll

if ($project.Kind -eq "{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") {
    $project.Object.References.AddFromFile($resourcesDll)
} else {    
    $project.Object.References.Add($resourcesDll)
}
```

**`Uninstall.ps1`**

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

Write-Host "Removing Foo.Resources reference"
$project.Object.References | where { $_.Name -eq 'Foo.Resources' } | foreach { $_.Remove() }
```

Comment: Thanks! this really helped us. it'd been driving me crazy why my blah.resources.dll wouldn't add a reference.

Comment: It seems that this workaround means that the package can't be updated from the command line any more and powershell commands are not run  from the command line update. Grrrr...

Answer (score 1):

This fork of NuGet has changes that would address this, however given the additional complexity I'm not sure it will ever make it into master: https://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/jjgonzalez/1644/contribution/5459