# Nuget: The package ID is reserved - when it is not

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I tried publishing my first nuget package to nuget.org. But I get the error "The package ID is reserved". My package has the ID "Joa.API".

During my research, I found 3 reasons why this error could occur:

1. **The package ID is already taken**:
   I searched on nuget.org and can't find any packages with the same ID. This does not seem to be the problem.
2. **The package prefix is already taken**:
   I searched on nuget.org for any packages with the same prefix. I don't find any. This does not seem to be the problem.
3. **The package ID contains reserved words**:
   The only reserved word I could find was "Resource": [Nuget package id reserved word restrictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570281/nuget-package-id-reserved-word-restrictions). My ID does not contain this word. This does not seem to be the problem.

So my Question is, which of my assumptions is wrong?

Comment: _which of my assumptions is wrong?_: The assumption that _This does not seem to be the problem_.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, which one of the three "This does not seem to be the problem" do you mean? I assume not all three are wrong. Can you explain why the assumption is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refer to these:
[Package ID prefix reservation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/id-prefix-reservation)
[NuGet Reserved Package ID Prefixes](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/nuget-reserved-package-id-prefixes-jj-van-zon/)
[Nuget package id reserved word restrictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570281/nuget-package-id-reserved-word-restrictions)

It seems like that you are using an existing package id while publishing the package, or there is some reserved word. Please review these links and they will help you find the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry, I should have mentioned that I already studied these links. But they don't really help in my situation. "Joa.API" does not contain any reserved words, and I can't find any existing package with the same name or prefix.

Comment: I have edited the question. It should now better reflect my thought process. I hope it is clearer now.