# How can I set up a resx file so it is editable by the user of the application

Tags: c#, dll, resources

I am integrating DLLs into an application where the DLLs are developed 12 time zones away in Russia. Coordination is difficult. I transfer data to the DLLs in dictionaries. To make sure I am using the correct keys required by the DLLs, I have set up a resource file. I will have the Russian developers edit the resource file to make sure the strings are correct. It would be nice if after they edit the file, they could immediately test the changes with the application I have built, hence the question about users editing resources. If they can't do this, then they will have to email the new resource file, so I can include it in the next build. This results in a 24 hour delay that I would like to avoid.

I am really not familiar with using resources, and I suspect this use is not normal. Any help would be appreciated.

BTW, I cannot see their code, and they cannot see mine.

Comment: I think what you want is Satellite Assemblies. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365569/what-is-a-satellite-assembly and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. This assumes that your offshore developers are using Visual Studio. They should be able to compile the resource to a DLL, copy it to the proper place in your application's file hierarchy, and run the app.

Comment: In general, what you're looking for is "localization". There are many articles about localization in general, and a few that discuss how to work in a distributed environment. You'll need to spend some time with your favorite search engine.

Comment: This app is already using localization for different languages. This resource file would be separate from the language specific resources.

Comment: Same principles apply.

Answer (score 0):

Recently,I had to build an application as proof of concept for editing Resource Files.Hopefully this is similar to what you are looking for.

[Edit Resource Files](http://code217.blogspot.com/2013/01/c-editupdate-resource-files-in.html)