# C# project resource file not found

Tags: c#, resource-files

I cloned a project to VS 2022 and I am trying to debug the code, but I am facing an error with the resource file:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Plugins.resources', Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=en-GB, The system cannot find the file specified.'

For some reason the project could not find the file.

I tried recreating the entire file and it didn't work.

I also tried moving the resource file to another folder or inside the project properties and also it didn't work

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365569/what-is-a-satellite-assembly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.